# How does foreach work in Pig?

Tags: foreach, apache-pig

I have a sample data looks like:

```
1950,0,1
1950,22,1
1950,-11,1
1949,111,1
1949,78,1
```

and I used following commands:

```
    A = load 'path/to/the/sample';
    B = foreach A generate $0,$1;
```

which should only generate first 2 columns of the A.
then I used

```
describe B
```

to check how it works, it returns: B: {a: bytearray,b: bytearray}, that is correct.

HOWEVER, when I run the command

```
dump B
```

why it returns:

```
(1950,0,1,)
(1950,22,1,)
(1950,-11,1,)
(1949,111,1,)
(1949,78,1,)
```

as the result??? It's sooooo weird. I'v tried it several time... but still the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is because Pig by default tries to separate your data by tabs.  So when you pass it a line like

```
1950,0,1
```

it thinks it has found just a single field, `1950,0,1`.  Since you indicated that each line has two fields, the second field is just set to `NULL`.

So when you `GENERATE` the two fields you loaded, it prints out the tuple

```
(1950,0,1,)
```

If you were to `STORE` this instead of `DUMP`ing it you would see it more clearly.  Pig would store the data separated by tabs (again, the default), and your output file would look like

```
1950,0,1    
1950,22,1    
1950,-11,1    
1949,111,1    
1949,78,1
```

That's not very enlightening, so look instead what happens if you were to do this:

```
B = foreach A generate $0, "test";
store B into 'output';
```

Now the data in `output` would be

```
1950,0,1    test
1950,22,1   test
1950,-11,1  test
1949,111,1  test
1949,78,1   test
```

You can control what Pig uses as the field separator for both `LOAD` and `STORE` by using the clause `USING PigStorage(',')`.  The argument to `PigStorage` can be whatever character you like.  One other common one is `USING PigStorage('\n')`, which will load in each line as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

Use **PigStorage** Clause in your Load statement.

```
A = load 'path/to/the/sample' using PigStorage(',');

B = foreach A generate $0,$1;

dump B
```

now you will get the result that what u expect

(1950,0)

(1950,22)

(1950,-11)

(1949,111)

(1949,78)